# Filtrar tabla para no obtener registros duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
id  n1  n2  fecha
2   2   1   2018-12-20 12:21:19.603
4   3   3   2019-02-04 15:34:06.430
14  3   2   2019-02-13 09:02:44.230
3   4   1   2019-02-11 08:02:42.590
5   5   3   2019-01-18 07:26:45.017
7   6   3   2019-02-12 18:02:54.680
11  7   2   2019-02-13 08:40:33.280
12  7   3   2019-02-13 08:41:43.143
13  7   5   2019-02-13 08:42:42.090
10  7   8   2019-02-13 11:20:52.757
6   7   1   2019-02-13 12:01:57.477
8   8   1   2019-02-07 08:57:32.380
9   9   1   2019-02-05 18:33:13.477
```

Deseo establecer una consulta que me entregue el primer registro (de la fecha mas reciente) de cada registro en la columna n1, es decir, en este caso la consulta debería darme como respuesta:

```
2   2   1   2018-12-20 12:21:19.603
14  3   2   2019-02-13 09:02:44.230
3   4   1   2019-02-11 08:02:42.590
5   5   3   2019-01-18 07:26:45.017
7   6   3   2019-02-12 18:02:54.680
6   7   1   2019-02-13 12:01:57.477
8   8   1   2019-02-07 08:57:32.380
9   9   1   2019-02-05 18:33:13.477
```

He intentado hacerlo por Group by, order by y DISTINC, pero no logro obtener lo la respuesta que deseo.

Comment: Incluye el código que has probado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo más típico para esto es usar `ROW_NUMBER`. Por ejemplo:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n1 ORDER BY fecha DESC)
    FROM dbo.TuTabla
)
SELECT  id,
        n1,
        n2,
        fecha
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para insertar los resultados en una tabla variable, simplemente debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @TemporalTabla TABLE(id int, n1 int, n2 int, fecha datetime);

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n1 ORDER BY fecha DESC)
    FROM dbo.TuTabla
)
INSERT INTO @TemporalTabla
SELECT  id,
        n1,
        n2,
        fecha
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: muchas gracias, de verdad que me ha funcionado como lo necesitaba, una pregunta, como puedo guardar los resultados de esta consulta dentro de la siguiente tabla un: DECLARE @TemporalTabla TABLE ( id int, n1 int, n2 int, fecha datetime  )...... Agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: @WilliamRodriguez ahí actualicé mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

otra forma que te recomiendo y la utilizo en estos casos es; 
hacer un join contra un select agrupado, por ejemplo:

```
select Tabla1.id, Tabla2.n1, Tabla1.n2, Tabla1.fecha from Tabla1 join
(select n1, max(fecha)as fecha from Tabla1 group by n1)Tabla2
on Tabla1.n1=Tabla2.n1
```

Y, para insertar los registros en una tabla:

```
select Tabla1.id, Tabla2.n1, Tabla1.n2, Tabla1.fecha into TablaTemp from Tabla1 join
(select n1, max(fecha)as fecha from Tabla1 group by n1)Tabla2
on Tabla1.n1=Tabla2.n1
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, he intentado tu rutina, pero no la he logrado hacer funcionar, podrias por favor darnos mas detalles. Gracias.

Comment: Hola William, te detallo la consulta donde debes reemplazar el nombre de tu tabla por Tabla:[select Tabla.id, 
  Tabla2.n1, 
  Tabla.n2, 
  Tabla.fecha into TablaTemp from Tabl1 join (select n1, max(fecha)as fecha from Tabla group by n1)Tabla2 on Tabla.n1=Tabla2.n1
  
  select * from TablaTemp ]

Comment: Hola Daniel, agradezco tu ayuda, me ha funcionado conforme necesitaba, gracias.